# ¿Convertir lista python a Json?

Tags: python, json

tengo una lista de objetos en python

```
lista_datos = ['carlos@alberto.com | MARRUFO | 2020-06-05 | 1500 | 12347 | 2021-05-23 19:26', 'carlos@marrufo.com | CARLOSMARRUFO | 2020-01-02 | 522 | 12348 | 2021-05-23 19:30']
```

Tengo una función con la que intento pasar esa lista a un archivo Json, y lo logro, pero no divide los registros por comas, muestro el código:

```
def crearJson():
global lista_datos
archivo_json = open("datos_json.json", "w")
arreglo_json = {}
for registro in lista_datos:
    arreglo = registro.strip().split(" | ") #Para convertir el registro en un arreglo
    arreglo_json = {
        'correo': f'{arreglo[0]}',
        'nombre': f'{arreglo[1]}',
        'nacimiento': f'{arreglo[2]}',
        'monto': f'{arreglo[3]}',
        'folio': f'{arreglo[4]}',
        'momento': f'{arreglo[5]}'
    }
    archivo_json.write(json.dumps(arreglo_json))
```

Me guarda el archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
{"correo": "carlos@alberto.com", "nombre": "MARRUFO", "nacimiento": "2020-06-05", "monto": "1500", "folio": "12347", "momento": "2021-05-23 19:26"}{"correo": "carlos@marrufo.com", "nombre": "CARLOSMARRUFO", "nacimiento": "2020-01-02", "monto": "522", "folio": "12348", "momento": "2021-05-23 19:30"}
```

Como se puede ver, no separa los registros por coma, y eso genera error...
¿Alguien tiene uno idea de como puedo solucionar esto, u otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Si están separados por coma, además `json.dumps()` devuelve una representación del json en string

Comment: @Christian no, no están separados por coma...

Comment: listo respuesta publicada, avisame si tienes algun problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso estas escribiendo mal el archivo `.json`, pues tu progrma hace lo que le pides, solo escribe en el archivo, pero no separa. ¿Cómo podemos solucionar eso?, pues facil con un diccionario *padre* que almacene todos los sub diccionarios. supongamos que tu **JSON** representa a unos clientes.

```py
import json

def crearJson()
    ...
    #creamos un diccionario que contendrá todo
    json_data= {}
    #cada conjunto de datos son los datos de un cliente
    json_data['clientes'] = []

    for registro in lista_datos:
        arreglo = registro.strip().split(" | ") #Para convertir el registro en un arreglo
        arreglo_json = {
            'correo': f'{arreglo[0]}',
            'nombre': f'{arreglo[1]}',
            'nacimiento': f'{arreglo[2]}',
            'monto': f'{arreglo[3]}',
            'folio': f'{arreglo[4]}',
            'momento': f'{arreglo[5]}'
        }
    #añadimos a la lista del diccionario
    json_data['clientes'].append(arreglo_json)

    #escribimos
    with open("datos_json.json", "w") as archivo_json
        #escribimos y especificamos la identacion (4 espacios)
        archivo_json.write(json.dump(json_data, indent=4))
```

Esto seria el proceso correcto para crear y escribir un **JSON**, algo que habrás visto es que utilizamos la sentencias `with` lo cual nos permite manipular el archivo sin tener que preocuparnos por cerrarlo, ya que si lo dejamos abierto consumirá memoria. puedes leer mas sobre el uso del modulo [JSON](https://docs.python.org/es/3.9/library/json.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Christian, sin duda me pondré a leer sobre el módulo JSON.